# Why is an error occurring even when a bit of the code is not executed?

Tags: python, error-handling

I have the following code:

```
lista = ["T","E","S","T"]
for i in range (20):
    if i <= len(lista):
        print(lista[i])
```

Python gives me an error, saying:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Now, to me this doesn't make sense because I'm testing if the list index is out of range with my `if` command. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `len()` of a list is going to be higher than the index allowed. If `lista = ["T","E","S","T"]` -> `len(lista)` -> 4 (there are 4 items in your list). However with 0 index, this corresponds to indexes of 0, 1, 2, and 3....there is no "4" index. You can try:

```
lista = ["T","E","S","T"]
for i in range (20):
    if i <= len(lista) - 1: # account for index error
        print(lista[i])
```

Comment: Or just use `<`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes that is valid as well! I was just trying to show that it will work if you explicitly decrease it by one to avoid the "off by one" errors.

Comment: Would be simpler to use `if i < len(lista):`.

Comment: @ZadSar Not stupid, just thinking about the problem incorrectly. It happens to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your check is incorrect. The last index in a list with 4 elements is 3, not 4 (remember, indexes start at 0, not 1).

Change your check to:

```
if i <= len(lista) - 1:
```

As noted in the other answer, or, more commonly:

```
if i < len(lista):
```

This code is set up odd though. Why create a `range` with 20 elements, then ignore the last 16? Use the length of the list to create the `range`:

```
for i in range(len(lista)):
    print(lista[i])
```

Or, even better, just loop over the list directly:

```
for elem in lista:
    print(elem)
```